# Is this set open? By considering the pre-image under continuous functions of open sets

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus

> Is the set $S=\left\{(x,y,z)\in{\mathbb{R^3}}: \dfrac{(e^{x+y^2−z}−1)}{(x^2+y^2−z^3)}>7\right\}$open, closed,
>   or neither in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

I am trying to consider the continuous functions $f(x,y,z):=x^2+y^2-z^3,$ and $g(x,y,z):=e^{x+y^2-z}-1-7(x^2+y^2-z^3)$. I want to use the facts that their pre-images of open sets are open, and that an arbitrary union of open sets also is open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should notice that the function $f(x,y,z)=\frac{e^{x+y^2-z}-1}{x^2+y^2-z^3}$ is only well defined on $X=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3| x^2+y^3 \neq z^3\}$. The set $X$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Second, I assume that you knew about continuous function on topological spaces so you should know the following general statement:

*Let $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function on a topological space $X$. Then $f^{-1}(\{t> a\})$ is an open set in $X$* for every $a \in \mathbb{R}$

It follows from the continuity of $f$ that the preimage of open sets are open sets and the fact that $\{t >a\}$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R}$.

So, as conclusion, your set $S=f^{-1}(\{t>7\})$ is an open set in $X$, which is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Therefore, $S$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Bonus: S is not a closed set in $\mathbb{R}^3$ since otherwise, $S$ is a closed and open set in $\mathbb{R}^3$, hence $S=\mathbb{R}^3$ since $\mathbb{R}^3$ is connected. This is a contradiction since $S \subset X \neq \mathbb{R}^3$.